# Parameters regarded as column names, not column values using Dynamic SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, dynamic

This is my first time here and I want to ask a question.

Here is my stored procedure...

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetDataFromTable]
@tablename sysname,
@DocumentName nvarchar(50),
@Uploader nvarchar(50)

as
begin

if @tablename = 'Document_Data'
EXEC('Select * from Document_Data where DocumentName = ('+ @DocumentName +') and Uploader = ('+ @Uploader +')')

end
```

and the problem is... the stored procedure reads the DocumentName and Uploader parameters as column names, not the values themselves. I already tried to use aliases and other things that I scoured from the Internet, but they don't work.

What could be the problem behind this? Oh, and BTW I am a newbie to Dynamic SQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `''` chars to dynamic sql after and before your parameters as below:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetDataFromTable]
@tablename sysname,
@DocumentName nvarchar(50),
@Uploader nvarchar(50)

as
begin

if @tablename = 'Document_Data'
EXEC('Select * from Document_Data where DocumentName = ('''+ @DocumentName +''') and Uploader = ('''+ @Uploader +''')')

end
```

Comment: Thank you, kind sir. I didn't think that earlier. Thanks.

How do I regard this as answer?

Comment: @JephElijay If the answer is helpful for you don't forget to accept the answer to close the question and close the question. You can also vote for the answer.